# Can I count the number of results in my Lucene query

Tags: sensenet

I would like to create a smart folder to count how many items I have with certain conditions. I have not found any command in the wiki to make the query return the number of results instead of the items themselves.
Thanks in advance.

BR,
Szeki

Comment: Pls clarify where do you want to see the result: in server-side code, on the old webforms GUI, or on the client side.

Comment: @miklós-tóth, I wanted to see the result in Content Explore's right panel (on the old webforms GUI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.COUNTONLY is the term that you are looking for.

You can find examples [here](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Content_Query_API#Built-in_safe_queries)

Comment: Thanks, @aniko-litvanyi. Looks to be the parameter I'm looking for, however I get this error when adding this extra parameter to my smart folder's query:
' Modification Date
ListView error: Unexpected ')' (query: "+(+Type:User +CreationDate:>'2018-04-11' +InTree:'/Root/IMS/AAA' +(-Id:6660) .COUNTONLY)") [Line: 3, Col: 49]'

This is my query:
'+Type:User  
+CreationDate:>'2018-04-11'
+InTree:'/Root/IMS/AAA' .COUNTONLY'

It works fine without the .COUNTONLY.

Comment: The workaround is to change the order, because countounly now cannot be the last one (it is a bug for sure), btw the count is not displayed anywhere on the ui, so the related view should be modified or you have to create a custom view.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the order and don't get the error anymore, but the count is not shown either as you mentioned. So I will adjust the view then.